# Is button in header valid ? <h1><button> Caption </button></h1>

Tags: html, button, header, accessibility, markup

Is this possible or is it not valid?

```
<h1>
  <button>
     Caption
  </button>
</h1>
```

This header is the heading of an accordion. Therefore its a button as it opens and closes the accordion but semantically its a header as its the important chapters of the page. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) instead of opening a new question every time you want to know if your HTML is valid.

Now to your question - yes it is **valid**.